# Cron não funciona

Tags: linux, cron

Estou tentando executar um arquivo `.sh` para realizar um backup da minha base de dados, mas por algum motivo a cron para executar este arquivo não está funcionando.

Já tentei fazer várias alterações, mas nada funciona. Todas as outras cron funcionam normalmente, menos esta que deveria executar o arquivo de backup do meu DB.

Obs: O arquivo funciona e gera um backup do DB normalmente quando o executo na linha de comando.

Segue o meu código:

```
#!/bin/bash
# mobcliDB_bkp.sh
DATA=$(date '+%d-%m-Y-%T')
NOME="/root/data/mobcliDB_bkp-$DATA.sql"

HOST="localhost"
USER="root"
PASSWORD="*******"
DATABASE="mobcliDB"

/usr/bin/mysqldump -h $HOST -u $USER -p$PASSWORD $DATABASE > $NOME

zip -r /root/data/mobcliDB_bkp-$DATA.zip $NOME

rm /root/data/mobcliDB_bkp-$DATA.sql
```

A cron está assim:

```
*/5 * * * * /meu diretorio/mobcliDB_bkp.sh
```

Tenho outras cron no mesmo arquivo que funcionam normalmente.

Comment: Se rodar manualmente o comando, funciona?

Comment: @GabrielSantos Rodando manualmente funciona normal!

Comment: é pra rodar de 5 em 5 minutos?

Comment: @GabrielSantos Quando funcionar, irei colocar para rodar 1 vez por dia, mas por enquanto deixei de 5 em 5 minutos para testar e ver se está funcionando.

Comment: *Pode* ser o zip que não está sendo reconhecido. Tente colocar o caminho absoluto para ele.

Comment: Provavelmente é algum problema de permissão. O script está acessível e executável para o usuário em que você está habilitando o crontab? Confira os logs do cron em /var/log/cron e veja o que pode estar errado.